# How to handle uncertainty of after login page loading in karate

Tags: karate

In my application it is using multiple layers for login like application send request to Okta after that okta send request to GCP with user information and after that only login made successful.
I have created login feature as:

```
            * driver fdiPortalUrl
            * maximize()
            * retry(50, 1000).waitForUrl('/login')
            * call read 'classpath:fdiPortalUI/fdiPortalPageObjects.json'
            * if (exists(loginPage.username)) click(loginPage.username)
            * if (!exists(loginPage.username)) reload()
#           * retry(50, 1000).waitFor(loginPage.username)
            * retry(30, 1000).waitForUrl('/login')
            * match text(loginPage.usernameLabel) contains 'Username'
            * match text(loginPage.passwordLabel) contains 'Password'
            * input(loginPage.username, username)
            * input(loginPage.password, password)
            * waitForEnabled(loginPage.signInBtn).click()
            * retry(20, 1000).waitForUrl('/auth/callback')
            * retry(50, 1000).waitForUrl('/inventory-management')
```

Even after these delays and retry some times it fails at last line. I want to make it dynamic like if it fails at end and not able to find `/inventory-management` in url so it reload the page again.
can you please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there's no short-cut to this, you have already tried retry etc.

Maybe it is time to consider advanced techniques like mocking parts of your UI or using API's to avoid login etc: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#hybrid-tests

Else I have nothing else to suggest. Maybe others here can help.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I will try with hybrid :)